# How to change color of each icon separately after clicked on it?

Tags: css, react-native

I am using RN vector icon for bookmark purpose.

Current behavior:
I have multiple photos with icon on it, when i clicked on any icon of any photo all icon's color get changed.

Expected behavior:
When i press any icon, only that icon's color should be changed, not all.

How should i achieve it?

i have following code:

```
this.state = {
  toggle: false,
}


<TouchableHighlight>
  <Icon name="ios-ribbon" onPress={()=> this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle})} size={30} style={[styles.icon, this.state.toggle && styles.iconAlt]} /> 
</TouchableHighlight>
```

style

```
icon: {
 color: '#000',
 height: 40,
 marginLeft: 60,
 marginRight: 60,
 marginBottom: 30,
 padding: 2,
},
iconAlt: {
 color: '#ff6600',
},
```

[image]

This is normal condition i.e before clicked on any icon

[image]

After clicked on any single icon, All icons color get changed

Comment: Could you add the part of the code where you actually use the component? Having the rest of the component code could also help to triage the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this seems like a question about changing the color of the icon, but really beyond that in my opinion.

Let's say each product has only a `title` and an `image`, these 2 states. The color of the icon indicates whether a user has added this product to his/her favorite, therefore, a product should also have a state called `favorite`, which is boolean. Since each product has different states, let
's make a `PureComponent` called `Product` like so:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

class Product extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            image: '',
            favorite: false
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const { title, image, favorite } = this.props;
        this.setState({ title, image, favorite });
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    }

    render() {
        const { title, image, favorite } = this.state;

        return (
            <View style={{ ... }}>
                <Text style={{ ... }}>
                    {title}
                </Text>
                <Image
                    source={image}
                    style={{ ... }}
                />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Icon
                        name={favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                        color={favorite ? '#F44336' : 'rgb(50, 50, 50)'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 20 }}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({ favorite: !favorite })}
                    />
                    <Text style={{ ... }}>
                        {favorite ? 'Remove from favorite' : 'Add to favorite'}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Product;
```

And in our main screen, we have an array of products, then we put them in a `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.products}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Product
            title={item.title}
            image={item.image}
            favorite={item.favorite}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Then, you will have this, it looks very ugly, just style it a little bit, bear with me here:

[image]